# Validation application block 5 and WPF view model

Tags: validation, enterprise-library, viewmodel

My question is quite basic and to do with validating an object in your view model using enterprise library validation application block 5.0.

It seems that when a user enters invalid data, whilst the UI displays the error template for a control, the property in the view model that the control is bound to does not get updated.

This is a problem as I wanted to call code such as this

```
ValidatorFactory factory = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<ValidatorFactory>();
myValidator = factory.CreateValidator<Customer>();

ValidationResults results = myValidator.Validate(this.CustomerProperty);
if (!results.IsValid)
{
    // etc
}
```

in my save button command in the view model to check that the data is valid.

Example of problem I'm having.

e.g.
If I have a textbox bound to a string property in the vm with a string length validator (min length 1, max 10) then the following could happen;

1. Enter text of 'ABC'.
   UI does not show error.
   View model property updated to 'ABC'.
2. Delete contents of textbox (so now invalid).
   UI now shows error (good).
   But view model property is now out of sync with UI. Property in the view model is still set to ABC.
3. Save validation will still pass as the view model data is still valid.

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I ended up removing the validationRule (as per the example in the EntLib 5 hands-on labs documentation) and implemented IDataErrorInfo in my Customer class.

I then changed my XAML and in my textbox binding added

```
ValidatesOnDataErrors=True
```

This then validates my object as I'd expect. i.e. Invalid data is propagated to the view model property which I can then validate on my save command.